# GoLang extension through Visual Studio Code: Imports do not work. Builds and Tests fine from regular command line

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am testing this very simple Go code on MacOS using VS Code.  The project consists of these sample packages / files:

1. azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/main/main.go
2. azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/service.go
3. azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/tests/test.go
4. azure.com/myproj/internal/common/common.go

On the terminal command line, everything builds and all tests pass:
    go build .   // (works in every folder)
    go test .    // (tests work and pass)

However, from VS code I have 2 problems:
1. Imports from package to package do not work at all. For example:

```
package test

import (
    service "azure.com/myproj/cmd/service"    // VS complains on this line when running the test.
)
```

2. The command that VS code runs is not just "go test . ".  It passes extra parameters that include what seems to be a cached path, which I tried deleting from the file system, but it did not have an effect.   This is what VS.code's Output tab contains:

Go Tests tab:

```
unknown import path "azure.com/myproj/cmd/service": 
cannot find module providing package 
azure.com/myproj/cmd/service
```

Go tab:

```
/Users/computername/go/src/azure.com/projname/cmd/service/tests 
>Finished running tool: /usr/local/bin/go test -c -o 
/var/folders/q5/hm9v_6x53lj0gj02yxqtkmd40000gn/T/vscode-goKGOMES/go- code-check azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/tests
can't load package: package 

azure.com/myproj/cmd/service: unknown import path 
"azure.com/myproj/cmd/service": cannot find module 
providing package azure.com/myproj/cmd/service
```

I do not understand what VS code is doing above with **hm9v_6x53lj0gj02yxqtkmd40000gn** and how I can change it.  It looks like a cache.

So to summarize:  When testing through VS Code, i do not understand why it's using the command that it is to run the tests (above), and why it can not find the imports, which the regular  "go build . " and "go test . " commands have no problem with through the terminal.

Once again:  From the terminal command line everything builds and all tests pass.

Seems to clearly be a VS Code related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.  VS did not like the file path structure for the project.  Here are the changes I made:

1. Moved main.go from azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/main/main.go up a level to azure.com/myproj/cmd/service/main.go
2. Moved the service implementation (service.go) into the internal folder:  azure.com/myproj/internal/service/service.go
3. Moved the tests into the internal folder: 
   azure.com/myproj/internal/service/test/service_test.go

How VS code is able to run the tests without complaining of the imports not being found.

So now I only have the main.go in my /cmd/service folder.  Everything lives in Internal, including tests.   I suspect that burying main.go into a subfolder is what was confusing VS Code.